# Person who never talks in commanding manner

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, translation

What is a single word for a person who never talks with anyone in commanding manner in any situation?

I prefer an adjective that can be used when explaining the quality of a person.

Comment: Do you want a noun or an adjective? Is it absolutely never or just usually? Can you give a sentence where the word would go? Any other nuances that might help?

Comment: I prefer an adjective. Absolutely never. While explaining the quality of a person.

Comment: What did a thesaurus show you already that is nearby but just not right?

Comment: Soft-spoken......

Comment: I think your requirement of 'never' is superfluous. Adjectives in English, used with 'is', say nothing about permanence (unlike say ser and estar in Spanish which distinguish between permanent and temporary. Few things in English are permanent. Even medically restricted things (tongueless?) could be overcome. Also, there are lots of possibilities: meek, introverted, speechless, mute, dumb, stroke-victim, silent, boring, corpse-like.  Maybe a thesaurus will help?

Comment: Are you a native speaker? Do you know there is such a word but just can't come up with it immediately? Are you non-native and have such a word in your native language?

Comment: Hello. Welcome, again, Note that the single-word-request tag "is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. "

Comment: @Mitch I am non-native. In my Telugu language, we call *methaka* or *methuvu*

Comment: My naive attempts at blindly using online translation (google translate and http://telugudictionary.telugupedia.com/), gave nearby words  మెతక
or మెతుక metaka [Tel.] adj. Slack, loose, soft, soil free from gravel. So this sounds like, when used for people, as a metaphor for someone who is not strong or commanding. All of the suggested words _could_ work in translation (translation depends a lot on context because every word has multiple connotations). Some ideas (not yet mentioned): 'meek', 'shy', or 'timid' ([antonym of 'confident'](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confident)).

Answer (score 5):

**Unassertive**

It means not [assertive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assertive), where assertive is defined as:

> disposed to or characterized by bold or confident statements and behavior
>
> - an assertive leader

Answer (score 4):

**Humble** (adjective) [**<sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/humble)

> *Meaning*: Having or showing a modest or low estimate of one's importance
>
> > *Usage*: "Ever since he lost the election for Taipei mayor, he has been humble and self-restrained, quiet and modest, to the surprise of many."

Answer (score 3):

A nice rare word is ***obsequent***, and it is defined with a list of synonyms:

> Compliant, yielding, obedient; deferential, servile.
>   <sub>[Oxford *Living* Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obsequent)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**reticent** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/164265?redirectedFrom=reticent#eid)

a. Reluctant or disinclined to speak out or express personal thoughts and feelings freely; reserved in speech; given to silence or concealment.

As in:

> A reserved and reticent person, she nonetheless could deliver a good
>   speech.

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on what connotation you want and to what effect, but you can try any of the following terms:

- [unassertive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unassertive?s=t)
- [mealy-mouthed](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mealy-mouthed?s=t)
- [soft-spoken](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/soft-spoken?s=ts)
- [resigned](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/resigned?s=t)
- [acquiescent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/acquiescent)
- [easygoing](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/easy-going?s=t)
- [chill](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chill?s=t)

If you're looking for nouns, you might try:

- a [pushover](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pushover?s=t)
- a [softy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/softy)
- a [fatalist](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fatalist?s=t)
- a [sub](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sub) (i.e., a submissive person, as opposed to a "dom," meaning a dominant person)
- a [beta](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beta)

Comment: Although "beta" fits, I'd avoid "beta" because it's potentially offensive (it's often used to insult men who are not sufficiently gender conforming in the eyes of the user).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more positive definition, you might like [mild](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/mild?s=t)-mannered.

> adjective, mild·er, mild·est.
>
> ```
> amiably gentle or temperate in feeling or behavior toward others.
> characterized by or showing such gentleness, as manners or speech: a mild voice.
> ```